# Which Hindu religious scripture talks about Rahu Kaal?

Tags: nakshatra, rahu

Internet is full of information like how Rahu Kaal is calculated, what activities should not be started during Rahu kaal, etc. But nowhere is the source of this information mentioned. In which original authentic Hindu scripture is the Rahu Kaal mentioned ?